# Android Things firmware flash on intel edison fails from windows 10 system

Tags: intel-edison, android-things

I have followed all the steps as given in the google android things page. I am using the latest Intel Platform Flash tool 5.8.3 v for windows.
When i try to flash the FlashEdison.json image it runs upto 50% and then fails.

my desktop config: Windows 10 Pro - 64 bit version

Please see the log below. If anyone has any clues please let me know.

```
 04/30/17 12:30:29.498  INFO   : Intel(R) Platform Flash Tool Lite V 5.8.3.0 x86 (build on Friday February 24th 2017, 06:50:07 UTC)
04/30/17 12:30:29.498  INFO   : Using xFSTK Downloader version: 1.8.1
04/30/17 12:30:29.603  INFO   : Using DFU Downloader version: 0.8.4-msvc
04/30/17 12:30:29.603  INFO   : Using DnX Firmware Downloader version: 1.0.0.0 (API: 3.0.0.1108(DBG))
04/30/17 12:30:30.066  INFO   : Using Intel Command Line FlashTool v.2.64 (Download Library v.5.31,0.0 )
04/30/17 12:30:30.182  INFO   : Using Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.35
Revision 68de85bda98d-android
04/30/17 12:30:30.182  INFO   : No external tool registered
04/30/17 12:30:30.182  INFO   : OS version detected: Windows 10 (x64)
04/30/17 12:30:30.182  INFO   : SSL supported: No
04/30/17 12:30:30.283  INFO   : Disk space available on drive C:/ : 146.17 GB
04/30/17 12:30:30.467  INFO   : Adb and fastboot binaries OK
04/30/17 12:30:31.656  INFO   : Platform Flash Tool Lite initialized successfully
04/30/17 12:30:47.707  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] New device detected on 0/10/2 (id=0009010000000002)
04/30/17 12:31:04.631  INFO   : Ready to flash!
04/30/17 12:31:04.647  INFO   : Flash file F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\FlashEdison.json [Non_OS] loaded
04/30/17 12:31:09.584  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Start flashing the flash configuration with dnx_fw start state for 14EA675742D759AF211B0BC01068EBC5
04/30/17 12:31:09.586  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Starting flash ...
04/30/17 12:31:09.586  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Running `Notify Please reset the edison (with reset button)` command
04/30/17 12:31:09.593  INFO   : Displaying notification during 42000 ms
04/30/17 12:31:09.596  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Command `Notify Please reset the edison (with reset button)` succeed
04/30/17 12:31:09.596  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Running `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Platform Flash Tool Lite\xfstkFlashTool.exe" "-1" "F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\edison_dnx_fwr.bin" "F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\edison_ifwi-dbg-00.bin" "F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\edison_dnx_osr.bin" "F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\u-boot-edison.img" "0x80000007" "none" "none" "0"` command
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Disabling xFSTK Misc DnX
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Disabling xFSTK wipe out ifwi option
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Using xFSTK Solo interface (new API)
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] xFSTK Soft Fuse not set
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK Downloader API 1.8.1
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Copyright (c) 2015 Intel Corporation
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] fwdnx -- F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\edison_dnx_fwr.bin
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] fwimage -- F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\edison_ifwi-dbg-00.bin
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] osdnx -- F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\edison_dnx_osr.bin
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] osimage -- F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\u-boot-edison.img
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] gpflags -- 0x80000007
04/30/17 12:31:09.681  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] softfuse --
04/30/17 12:31:09.762  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK-STATUS--Detecting Intel Device - Attempt #0
04/30/17 12:31:10.904  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] ....XFSTK-LOG--virtual bool MerrifieldDownloader::SetDevice(IGenericDevice*)
04/30/17 12:31:10.904  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Initiating download...
04/30/17 12:31:10.907  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK-STATUS--FW download is in progress ...
04/30/17 12:31:10.908  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK-STATUS--FW: Sending DnX DCFI00 ...
04/30/17 12:31:13.778  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK-STATUS--Error Code: 0 - Success
04/30/17 12:31:13.778  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK-STATUS--Firmware download completed. Continuing to OS...
04/30/17 12:31:23.925  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK-STATUS--Reconnecting to device - Attempt #1
04/30/17 12:31:25.070  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK-STATUS--POS download is in progress ...
04/30/17 12:31:27.997  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK-STATUS--Error Code: 0 - Success
04/30/17 12:31:27.997  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK-STATUS--Firmware and OS download completed.
04/30/17 12:31:27.997  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] XFSTK: Transfer Completed Successfully.
04/30/17 12:31:27.997  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Success: Download of FW Completed.
04/30/17 12:31:27.997  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] xfstkFlashTool exited with success
04/30/17 12:31:27.998  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Platform Flash Tool Lite\xfstkFlashTool.exe" "-1" "F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\edison_dnx_fwr.bin" "F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\edison_ifwi-dbg-00.bin" "F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\edison_dnx_osr.bin" "F:\Downloads\androidthings_edison_devpreview_3\u-boot-edison.img" "0x80000007" "none" "none" "0"` succeed
04/30/17 12:31:27.998  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Running `Wait for device with status pos on port 0/10/2` command
04/30/17 12:33:27.999  ERROR  : [Port 0/10/2] Command `Wait for device with status pos on port 0/10/2` failed
04/30/17 12:33:27.999  ERROR  : [Port 0/10/2] Flash failed (Command type: Device enumeration)
04/30/17 12:33:28.645  INFO   : [Port 0/10/2] Device lost on 0/10/2
```

Comment: Looks like the Tool waits for 2 minutes for the Edison to boot into POS mode. Failing to detect that, it exits. Try manually rebooting the device while it waits for it to boot to POS here "Running `Wait for device with status pos on port 0/10/2` command".

Comment: Also make sure Configuration is set to "Full" on your first full flash.

Comment: @shinymetal, Thanks for the information, how do i manually reboot the device? unplug the wire and plug it back?

Comment: Yes. Unplugging the USB OTG cable will do the trick. Also make sure you have the USB driver as @cjoyau mentioned. The device may be up in fastboot (The serial console would confirm that), but your host fails to enumerate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and noticed the [Intel USB Driver for Android Devices](https://software.intel.com/android/articles/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices) is listed as a pre-requisite in the The Intel Platform Flash Tool Lite homepage. Have you tried it ? After that installation went smoothly for me.